# How to ensure images display inside boundary on bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm a new but committed coder looking to create a website for a friend.
It is basic but coming along - but I keep having one major issue.

While the content displays correctly on desktop, on mobile I cannot stop the image from overflowing beyond the boundaries of the navbar. It's really frustrating because my Google maps and text page displays just fine as it should.

I know my HTML/CSS must look pretty ugly to experienced hands here but I'm looking to learn and improve on best practice approaches in future. Right now
my key goal is just to get this site up and build my skills from there.

I've looked to change a variety of code but to no luck so any insight into how to fix this would be really appreciated. My code is below...

[resize issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NNoF.jpg)
        **HTML**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed no-padding" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">  
    <div class="background">
      <div class="navbar-header"> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2 offset2"><br><br><br></div>  

         <div class="span5"><h4 class ="title1">Marvelous Grass Trees for Sale in Melbourne</h4></div>
        <br>

    </div> 
     </div>
     <div>  
    <ul class="nav">      
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a> 
    <li class="active"><a href="prices.html">Prices</a></li>     
    <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

     <br>
      <body> 
        <br>

             <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="imgAbt">

                  <img style='float:right;width:800px;height:600px; margin-right:10px;' src="Tree1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>       
            <div class="col-md-4" >
            <br>  
            <h1 class="header" style="padding-left:30px" >About Me</h1>    
                <p class="text" style="padding-left:30px" >Grass Trees are a protected species ...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>      

           <div class="container">
         <h1 class="header">About Me</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="imgAbt">

                  <img style='float:left;width:800px;height:600px; margin-right:10px;' src="Tree2.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p class="text">Our aim is to make these iconic plants...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>  
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>        

    <footer>    

    <div class ="social"> 
    <p class="text">You can also connect with us anytime on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/[page link to be created]">Facebook</a> to receive our latest news and special discounts available exclusively all our followers</p>
    </div>     


    <footer>
    <div class="footer1">&copy; 2018 Grass Trees</div>
    </footer> 

**CSS**


    html {
      overflow-x:hidden;
    }


    .jumbotron {
    background-color: #f5a600; 
    height: 100%;
     margin-right: -10px;
      margin-left: -10px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-top: 13px;
    }

    .navbar-fixed {
      width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -7px;   
    }

    no-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;  
    }

    .title1 {
     color: #467340;
    }

    h5 { 
    margin-top: -5px;   
    font-size: 41px;  
    text-align: center;  
    list-style-type: none;     
     letter-spacing: 7px; 
    color: yellow;    
    }

    .active {
    font-size: 35px;   
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 5%;  
    }

    .nav li.active a {
    color: #096445;   
    }

    .test {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #0d865d;  
    }

    .test1
    {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #668B8B;  
    }


    .cta {
    font-size: 20px;
    }


    .bodytext {
    text-align: center;    
    }


    .social {
    text-align: center;    
    }



    /* This is your footer section*/

    .footer1 {
    text-align: center;       
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-size: 10px;
      color: #000000;
      letter-spacing: 2px;

    }

    .iframe-container{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
    }
    .iframe-container > *{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .no-padding {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }

    .header {
    color: #096445; 
    }

    .text {    
    color: #17668f;
    }


    .img-responsive{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Ratio 16:9 ( 100%/16*9 = 56.25% ) */
    }
    .img-responsive > *{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

[Correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Mbr.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what specifically you want, however, the basic is

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

This will scale based on the parent block element

More info on the bootstrap documentation 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/

Good luck!

Ah it seems the img size is fixed

```
<img style='float:right;width:800px;height:600px; margin-right:10px;' src="Tree1.jpg" />
```

Use this instead

```
<img style="float:right;width:100%;height:100%; margin-right:10px;" src="Tree1.jpg" />
```

this will follow the col-md-6 size of its parent.
If you dot want to spread out too far use min-width max-width instead of fixed width

also tips :  use `<div style="height: 400px">` instead of `<br>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joseph.

I did try to use img-fluid previously but the same problem remained.

The goal is for the image width to not extend past the menu bar.

That's why I'm wondering if it's a matter of changing the menu bar instead of the image itself?

Comment: I tried running your code, I think I find the problem.